# How do I download new software with Windows Vista?

Tags: windows, windows-vista

I installed Windows Vista two days ago and now I have to install a new software.

I'm not aware with the functions of Windows Vista. How do I do it?

Comment: I'm wondering whether the question is about how to write an installer - i.e. what's changed from XP, where should executables live etc…

Answer (score 2):

The process has changed, to install a "system level" program, you will need to run it "as Administrator", this is done by "Right-Clicking" on the setup file and choosing "Run as Administrator", then accepting the UAC prompt.

If that doesn't work, it may prompt you to "Look for solutions", this is only useful if it is a well known program or game.

There are further options in "Compatibility", by choosing the "Properties" option from the right-click menu, you can try and emulate XP/2000 etc.. similar to the XP version.

Not all programs are compatible with Vista.

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow exactly the same process as you do on Windows XP or Windows 7. Just click on Setup or Install or whatever exists. In other words, you need to execute an installer in the same way that you did on Windows 95, Windows NT, Windows 2000, etc. Nothing has changed in this matter.

Answer (score 0):

You just install it the same way you do on other versions of Windows. The only difference is if you were using an older version of Windows before. Then Vista may ask you to allow it to change files. If you are sure you want to install it, click OK.